# removing white space in numbers when trim and clear doesn't work

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, number-formatting, array-formulas

I have a spreadsheet filled with numbers like this:

```
2 539.39
1 277.36
2 881.42
2 559.00
```

Google sheet doesn't identify them as a number until I remove the space:

```
2539.39
1277.36
2881.42
2559.00
```

however I've tried trim, clear and replace but I'm not able to remove this space. It is probably something else than a space.

What should I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
=SUBSTITUTE(A1," ",)
```

works fine, trim and clear do not remove single spaces in the middle of a string. If your space is always going to be the second character you can use replace as follows:

```
=replace(A1,2,1,"")
```

However replace will not remove all spaces anywhere like the above substitute method.

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(A1:A="",,SUBSTITUTE(A1:A, " ", )*1))
```

[image: 0]

but if you want that space and still have number you can format it like:

[image: 0]